Where is rawValue defined in Color(rawValue)?
I'm trying to follow this tutorial on iOS app development and I don't understand how or where rawValue gets defined in the 3rd last line in this statement
import SwiftUI

enum Theme: String {
    case bubblegum
    case buttercup
    case indigo
    case lavender
    case magenta
    case navy
    case orange
    case oxblood
    case periwinkle
    case poppy
    case purple
    case seafoam
    case sky
    case tan
    case teal
    case yellow

    var accentColor: Color {
        switch self {
        case .bubblegum, .buttercup, .lavender, .orange, .periwinkle, .poppy, .seafoam,
             .sky, .tan, .teal, .yellow: return .black
        case .indigo, .magenta, .navy, .oxblood, .purple: return .white
        }
    }

    var mainColor: Color {
        Color(rawValue)
    }
}

I understand that rawValue is a property of a case in an enumeration
so presumably rawValue will point to some string associated with a case defined above.
But, how does is know which case we are using for mainColor? The property doesn't refer to self as in accentColor.
Also, it appears that this is a calculated property with no setter, so it's not getting set at run time either (not that the argument is named anyways)
Is rawValue defined somewhere in the import SwiftUI? If so, why?

mainColor is an instance computed property.  self is implied, but it can be explicitly stated.  That is the code could say:
var mainColor: Color {
   Color(self.rawValue)
}

Omitting self is idiomatically common.
Just as in accentColor, self will be a particular case.  That is, each case has a mainColor and a corresponding accentColor. There isn't a single mainColor for Theme.
In use you would say something like Theme.bubblegum.mainColor.
The actual value of rawvalue will be a String equivalent to the case name - this is generated because the enum declaration specifies a String raw type but no explicit raw value is provided.

ok thanks, so on further research, it looks like you can almost always omit self in swift. So in accentColor, self is called because there's no other way of referring to self right?

self is inferred if there is no local variable that collides. So if you had a property foo and a variable foo in your function then you would need to say self.foo to explicitly refer to the property if you didn't want the local variable. You also need to use self.foo to capture self in a closure; the compiler will give you an error if you do not.

This is a feature of the Swift compiler, where if you define an enum to have a rawValue of type String, it will automatically infer a rawValue for each case equal to its name in your source, unless you manually specify otherwise for a particular case. .bubblegum will have a rawValue of "bubblegum", .buttercup will have a rawValue of "buttercup", etc

The declaration enum Theme: String causes the Theme enum to conform to the RawRepresentable protocol:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/rawrepresentable
This protocol has rawValue as a property; in effect, it is injected into the enum.
The actual value of the rawValue property of a case of the enum depends upon other aspects of the enum declaration (as described in the above-linked page, and in the documentation). In this example, the value is simply the case name, rendered as a String.
So Color(rawValue) is an abbreviation of Color(self.rawValue). You say

The property doesn't refer to self as in accentColor.

...but that is not true; self is implicit. Since self.rawValue is a String, this calls the Color initializer that takes a String:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/color/init(_:bundle:)
And thus a Color with the same name (as a string) as the current case is fetched from the asset catalog.
